# Flex application to have transparent background on swf file

Tags: flash, apache-flex, transparency

I need to make a transparent web browser. I am doing it as flex project but may choose something else if required. Transparency work but not on swf files. It puts black background on swf files which are transparent by default. Here is my code:
browser.mxml - pastebin.com/WcJ0yJVs
browser-app.xml - pastebin.com/1UWzx2kZ
Here is the HTML I try to get fully transparent (including the swf file) - http://pastebin.com/WS9JJSah
And here is the swf file that the HTML one links to - http://www.aleosoft.com/res/flashtutorial_transparent.swf
Also if you try to open the swf directly through the browser, like typing "http://www.aleosoft.com/res/flashtutorial_transparent.swf" in the flex browser it doesn't show at all. Everything else works OK for now, just having problems with the swf files in the HTML pages.
I am building it in Adobe® Flash® Builder™ 4.6 but doesn't work on Adobe Flex Builder 3 too.
Edit: By transparent I mean, instead of the background of the page, I want it to show everything behind the flex window, the previous windows/desktop must be clickable/usable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an AIR app: it doesn't even run in the browser. It runs in its own VM.

Comment: True. I want to create a Flex desktop application that acts as a browser, with the difference that instead of normal browsers, it should have transparent and invisible background, and everything from desktop behind this background to be clickable. I am not going to run my application in the browser.

Comment: Then why the embed code? Why don't you just run a transparent AIR app? I'm afraid I still don't understand.

Comment: The embed code is in the HTML page I am trying to open with the flex browser I am trying to create. Meaning, I am trying to create a flex browser, with the code of the first 2 pastebin links, and with that browser I want to open the HTML page which embeds a swf file and everything except the leafs should not exist. It just puts a black background behind those leafs, while it shouldn't, this swf should stay transparent.

Comment: OK, I get it now. But why go through an intermediary HTML page then? Why don't you just load the second swf into the main (browser) application?

Comment: Well, the pages I want to use to browser with, have HTML and a swf file in it. The HTML file is just an example page.